# On tapping UITextField, DatePicker is appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datepicker

Have implemented the DatePicker inside UITableViewCell, when table scrolled some random UITextfields on tapping showing DatePicker, how to fix that, please guide. Below is my code:

```
// Inside cellForeRowAt:

if (indexPath.row == 4) {
                    cell.txtFieldValue.tag = 24
                    cell.txtFieldValue.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dp(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)
                    nCell.txtFieldValue.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.setTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))

                }

@IBAction func dp(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if (sender.tag == 22 || sender.tag == 24) {
        let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
        datePickerView.maximumDate = Date()
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        let now = Date()
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:now)
        
            let selectedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
            datePickerView.setDate(selectedDate!, animated: true)
       
        if(sender.tag == 24) {
            datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
           
        } else if(sender.tag == 22) {
            datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDOBDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            
        }
    }
    print("tag: ", sender.tag)
}

@objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    selectedEffectiveDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    print(selectedEffectiveDate as Any)
    
}
```

Problem here is, some other text fields which are supposed to open keyboard also opening Date picker but not all textfields. what causing I am not getting please guide

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one section, then the row numbering starts from the beginning for each section. According to the code you have added above in every 5th line of each section the DatePicker will open. So it is normal for DatePicker to open after the 5th line that you will see in the table view. If you want to open DatePicker only on the 5th row of the first section you must also add the check that it is the first section aka indexPath.section == 0.

```
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 4 { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, have managed that, section check is implemented in cellForRowAt: thus used tag 22 for index 2

Comment: Can you paste all the cellForRowAt: code please